# Firestore new document inside writebatch

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a couple of writes that I want to be done together.
So I used a write batch.

Since the write batch requires a document reference, I have been creating the document before that write batch operation.

`DocumentReference accountHistoryDoc = await queryResult.reference.collection('accountHistory').add({});`

This led to many empty documents. Since I'm still testing and debugging the app, I assume because of an exception after the creation of the document.

How can I make sure that an empty document isn't created in the case of failure?

I'm thinking of changing this line

```
wb.set(
  accountHistoryDoc,  // Change this line
  {
    'account': newAccount,
    'serverTimestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    'type': 'hisab',
  },
);
```

to

```
wb.set(
  await subscriberDoc.collection('accountHistory').add({}),// new line
  {
    'account': newAccount,
    'serverTimestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    'type': 'hisab',
  },
);
```

Is this my thinking correct?

---

Rest of code:

```
QuerySnapshot query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().uid)
        .where('mobile', isEqualTo: mobile)
        .get();

QueryDocumentSnapshot queryResult = query.docs.first;
DocumentReference subscriberDoc = queryResult.reference;
DocumentReference accountHistoryDoc = await queryResult.reference.collection('accountHistory').add({});  // < -- new empty document here

WriteBatch wb = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

// update the total account
wb.update(
  subscriberDoc,
  {
    'totalAccount': subscriber.totalAccount + newAccount,
  },
);

// add new document in account history
wb.set(
  accountHistoryDoc,
  await subscriberDoc.collection('accountHistory').add({}),
  {
    'account': newAccount,
    'serverTimestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    'type': 'hisab',
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `CollectionReference.doc()` without an argument, it generates a new unique `DocumentReference` *without already creating that document in the database*. You can then use this `DocumentReference` to create the new document inside the batched write.

Also see the documentation for the [FlutterFire `doc()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html).